# What it the signature for non-static property decorator in TypeScript 5?

Tags: typescript, typescript-5

Although the TypeScript 5 has been officially realized with new decorators, the decorators documentation is still about decorators of TypeScript 4 (for the 1st April 2023).

[image]

The signature of decorator functions has been changed.
Experimentally I have 2 parameters with `undefined` first one and metadata-like second one:

```
export default function VueReactiveDataField(
  ...blackBoxes: Array<unknown>
): void {

  console.log(blackBoxes);

  // ...

}

@VueComponentOptions
export default class ReactiveStateExperimentalSample {

  @VueReactiveDataField
  protected exampleReactiveField: string = "Experimental sample works fine";

}
```

The console output is:

[image]

What it their types and why first one is undefined?

### [ Appendix ] tsconfig.json

Of course is has not `"experimentalDecorators": true`.

```json
{
  "compilerOptions": {

    "target": "ES2020",
    "moduleResolution": "node",
    "allowSyntheticDefaultImports": true,
    "esModuleInterop": true,

    "strict": true,
    "noUnusedLocals": true,
    "noUnusedParameters": false, /* Actual for Vue3; see https://github.com/vuejs/vue-next/issues/4668 */
    "allowJs": true, /* Actual for Vue3; */
    "skipLibCheck": true,

    "baseUrl": "./",
    "paths": {
      "@Source/*": [ "./Source/*" ]
    },
    "declaration": true
  },
  "include": [
    "Project.d.ts",
    "Source/**/*",
    "Tests/**/*"
  ]
}
```

Comment: [Please replace images of text/code/logs/errors with plaintext versions.](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/a/285557/2887218)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can read about decorators in [ECMAScript decorators proposal](https://github.com/tc39/proposal-decorators#class-fields). Specifically for class field decorators the first argument is always `undefined`. For the second argument TS5 provides `ClassFieldDecoratorContext<This, Value>` helper type.

For example

```
function VueReactiveDataField(
  _: undefined,
  // `unknown` if you don't care about the type of the class where decorated
  // property belongs
  // `string` so that you can only decorate string properties
  context: ClassFieldDecoratorContext<unknown, string>
): void {
  console.log(_, context);
}

@VueComponentOptions
export default class ReactiveStateExperimentalSample {
  @VueReactiveDataField
  protected exampleReactiveField: string = "Experimental sample works fine";
}
```

Or make it generic

```
function VueReactiveDataField<
  This, 
  // Will only work for properties of type `string`, `number` or `string | number` (or `never` but that's boring)
  Value extends string | number
>(
  _: undefined,
  context: ClassFieldDecoratorContext<This, Value>
): void {
  console.log(_, context);
}

@VueComponentOptions
export default class ReactiveStateExperimentalSample {
  @VueReactiveDataField
  protected exampleReactiveField: string = "Experimental sample works fine";
}
```